# Why are the arguments to atan2 Y,X rather than X,Y?

Tags: math, arguments, conventions

In C the atan2 function has the following signature:

```
double atan2( double y, double x );
```

Other languages do this as well. This is the only function I know of that takes its arguments in Y,X order rather than X,Y order, and it screws me up regularly because when I think coordinates, I think (X,Y).

Does anyone know why atan2's argument order convention is this way?

Comment: Why is this tagged as language-agnostic?

Comment: @mgroves It happens in many languages

Comment: Because the same format appears in a LOT of languages. From the atan2 wiki entry: " It dates back at least as far as the FORTRAN programming language and is currently found in the C programming language's math.h standard library, the Java Math library, the C# static Math class, and elsewhere. Many scripting languages, such as Perl, include the C-style atan2 function.[1]"

Comment: I'm sorry it screws you up, but if it were (x,y) it would screw me up.

Comment: I wrote my first `Atan2()` in `BASIC` in the 80's and was not aware of any conventions at the time (I thought I had invented sliced bread) and I made the arguments `(x,y)`. Ever since then I get screwed up which way the arguments go. Maybe the OP had a similar experience. It is all a mater of what you are familiar with.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because it is related to arctan(y/x), so y appears first.

Here's a nice link talking about it a bit: [Angles and Directions](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10814)

Comment: Some programmer in the mists of time decided it made sense that way. (And why is it 'atan2'? Why not 'angle_for'? I used to think it was arctangent-squared...)

Comment: Yeah, arctan(y/x) happens so often that if arctan2 took x,y it would screw me up all the time. It's nice to just change the slash to a comma.

Comment: @alex - it's atan2 because it takes 2 arguments, to distinguish it from atan(), which expects you to do the y/x division beforehand.

Comment: That's not the only reason, atan() does not handle the difference when both x and y are negative, whereas atan2() does.

Comment: @1owk3y Thank, I fixed it.

Answer (score 13):

My assumption has always been that this is because of the trig definition, ie that

```
tan(theta) = opposite / adjacent
```

When working with the canonical angle from the origin, opposite is always Y and adjacent is always X, so:

```
atan2(opposite, adjacent) = theta
```

Ie, it was done that way so there's no ordering confusion with respect to the mathematical definition.

Comment: Soh Cah Toa is my pnemonic :)

Comment: 7th grade?  You must not have gone to public school :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a rectangle triangle with its opposite side called y, adjacent side called x:

tan(angle) = y/x

arctan(tan(angle)) = arctan(y/x)

Answer (score 1):

It's because in school, the mnemonic for calculating the gradient
is *rise over run*, or in other words dy/dx, or more briefly y/x.

And this order has snuck into the arguments of arctangent functions.

So it's a historical artefact. For me it depends on what I'm thinking
about when I use `atan2`. If I'm thinking about differentials, I get it right
and if I'm thinking about coordinate pairs, I get it wrong.

Comment: I wonder if it would be more clear if the variables were labeled dx and dy?

Answer (score 1):

The order is atan2(X,Y) in excel so I think the reverse order is a programming thing.  atan(Y/X) can easily be changed to atan2(Y,X) by putting a '2' between the 'n' and the '(', and replacing the '/' with a ',', only 2 operations.  The opposite order would take 4 operations and some of the operations would be more complex (cut and paste).

I often work out my math in Excel then port it to .NET, so will get hung up on atan2 sometimes.  It would be best if atan2 could be standardized one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more convenient if atan2 had its arguments reversed. Then you wouldn't need to worry about flipping the arguments when computing polar angles. The Mathematica equivalent does just that: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html

Way back in the dawn of time, FORTRAN had an ATAN2 function with the less convenient argument order that, in [this reference manual](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html), is (somewhat inaccurately) described as arctan(arg1 / arg2).

It is plausible that the initial creator was fixated on atan2(arg1, arg2) being (more or less) arctan(arg1 / arg2), and that the decision was blindly copied from FORTRAN to C to C++ and Python and Java and JavaScript.