# Why are the parameters to `atan2` “backwards”?

Tags: math

Why is it that the parameters to the [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function are “backwards”? Ie, why does it accepts coordinates in the form `y, x` instead of the standard `x, y`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are the arguments to atan2 Y,X rather than X,Y?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045630/why-are-the-arguments-to-atan2-y-x-rather-than-x-y)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because it's similar to `atan(y / x)`, with `y` as numerator and `x` as denominator.

Answer (score 8):

Probably because `atan2(y,x) = atan(y/x) ± nπ` and here, `y` and `x` come in the same order.

Answer (score 5):

The single argument version of arctangent requires the ratio of opposite divided by adjacent sides. This is y/x. It's fairly similar to say atan2(y,x) as it's remenicent of atan(y/x).